# Combine multiple form control observables and subscribe in a reactive form

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a form with multiple input fields (Eg: CID,LastName,FirstName,etc.). Requirement is to give one input on form submit. So on entering input in any of the fields values in the fields other than the entered field needs to be cleared

Instead of subscribing valuechanges for all the controls I plan to use some operators in Rxjs to combine it and use only one subscribe. What I found is combineLatest. So I just pushed all the controls into an array and planned to pass to combineLatest operator.

I have created a stackblitz. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xeqms6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```
handleFormChanges(){

    const controlArr=[];
    for (const field in this.formControls) {
      controlArr.push(this.formEl.get(field).valueChanges);
    }

      combineLatest(controlArr)
       .pipe(map(control=>{
         startWith('')
        return control;
       }))
      .subscribe((value)=>{

        // Here I need to write the logic to clear input fields other than the current one.
        console.log(value);

      })
  }
```

Problem with the code above is that subscribe is first triggered only after values are entered in all the field at least once. Subsequent triggers are working as expected.

What I needed is on every valuechanges subscribe callback needs to be invoked

Comment: Please share the link of your code too, your stackblitz link doesn't have the code you have written

Comment: Sorry my bad. Here is the link [link] (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xeqms6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Why you just don't subscribe to `yourform.valueChanges`  ? It doesn't need to be field by field

Comment: Yeah you're right I don't know why I didn't think about that. Thanks for your tip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  handleFormChanges() {
this.formEl.valueChanges
  .pipe(pairwise())
  .subscribe(([prev, current]) => {
    for (const field in prev) {
      if (prev[field] === current[field]) {
        this.formEl.get(field).setValue(null, { onlySelf: true });
      }
    }
  });
```

}

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xeqms6

Comment: Exactly what I needed. It's a new learning for me to use pairwise operator. Thanks for that.

Comment: Good luck with your journey.